# Angularjs using Monaca IDE and Onsen "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I'm writing a mobile app in the Monaca IDE, using Angularjs. I'm trying to attach an image to a submit form (take picture, or include picture from file).

I have this error message

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined.

I can't seem to figure out why its saying 'getPicture' is undefined, where else in the project should I define this function?

Any suggestions on a working version? Thank you in advance

```
//My directive where getPicture() is called
<ons-button ng-click="getPicture()" />

//rebateFormCtrl Controller
.controller('rebateFormCtrl', function(rebate, $scope) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.receipt == null) {
            ons.notification.alert({message: "Please attatch a picture of the receipt"});
        }
        rebate.submit($scope.model, $scope.receipt, function (err, rebate) {
            if (err) {
                angular.forEach(err, function (val, i) {
                    ons.notification.alert({title: i, message: val});
                });

            }
            else {
                console.log(rebate);
                $scope.rebates.current = rebate;
                $scope.myNavigator.pushPage('rebate.html');
            }
        });
    };
    $scope.getPicture = function () {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function (imageData) {
                $scope.receipt = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            },
            function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        );
    };
})

//rebate Factory
.factory("rebate", function ($http, Upload) {
    return {
        getById: function (id, callback) {
            $http.get(baseUrl + "rebates/" + id)
                .then(function (res) {
                    callback(null, res.data);
                },
                function (res) {
                    callback(res);
                });
        },
        submit: function (rebateData, receipt, callback) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "receipt";
            options.fileName = receipt.substr(receipt.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            options.params = rebateData;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(receipt, encodeURI(baseUrl + 'rebates'),
                function (res) {
                  //success
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
                    var rebate = JSON.parse(res.response);
                    callback(null, rebate);
                },
                function (res) {
                  //fail
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
                  errors = JSON.parse(res.body);
                  callback(errors);
                }
            , options);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Cordova and the Camera plugin, the error is telling you that the `getPicture()` method cannot be called on an undefined variable.

Which means that `navigator.camera` is not defined.

You can do a simple check like the following code to see if it's set or not.

```
if (typeof navigator.camera !== 'undefined') {
    //Execute your code here
}
```

If you are using ngCordova (or Ionic) they have a nice wrapper for this plugin and Angular http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/

Comment: Thank you for the check suggestion!

Comment: Where exactly were you suggesting to place this(sorry i'm VERY green to programming in general)? I tried placing it within the scope.getPicture , and the factory. I put in a notification to alert me that it was registering and still got the same result.

Comment: You have to put it around anywhere you call `navigator.camera`. Though it's normal to have this error on a browser when testing but you shouldn't have it on your phone... If so the problem is somewhere else. This is just a quick fix to prevent the error to be shown in your browser. Also you can use the try/catch syntax if you want to.

Comment: it was an issue with how the image was being received. Problem is resolved now, thanks for your help.